# Laravel: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.1

I was following the default documentation and Laracst tutorials to build an application. Here is the source, https://github.com/nasirkhan/laravel-5-starter-application

Installing a new instance form this source shows the following errors, can anyone please assist me to find the issue here?

I run the following commands,

1. `git pull git@github.com:nasirkhan/laravel-5-starter-application.git`
2. `composer install` then i got the following error.

after getting the error i tried to run `php artisan migrate` but the error was not resolved.

```
    
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel-5-starter.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)  

  [PDOException]                                                                                           
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel-5-starter.permissions' doesn't exist

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It’s telling you what the _exact_ problem is: the `permissions` table does not exist. You’ll need to run the migrations if you haven’t already.

Comment: In your `database\migrations` there is no `permissions` table available but it looks like you need to have that table and must migrate.

Comment: @MartinBean, @ the-alpha, i tried the migration too. updated the question description , it might help you to understand the problem easily

Answer (score 2):

found the [solution](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-doesnt-exist/replies/151761). Updated the repo, thanks for engaging.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan migrate` from the console. There seems to be a permissions table which is queried but doesn't exist yet.

In the file `2015_09_10_193651_create_roles_tables.php` the table gets created, [as you can see here](https://github.com/nasirkhan/laravel-5-starter-application/blob/master/database/migrations/2015_09_10_193651_create_roles_tables.php).

Comment: updated the question description , it might help you to understand the problem easily